# How do I match the union of two arrays in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two arrays: `users` and `projects`. IDs in both are unique numbers. A project can have more than one owner, so in `projects` I have an array of user IDs named `ownersId` that link to the `id` of users in `users`,  as seen here:

```
export const users = [{
    id: 1,
    givenName: 'Alexander',
    surname: 'Kelly',
    initials: 'AK'
}, {
    id: 2,
    givenName: 'Karen',
    surname: 'Jones',
    initials: 'KJ'
}, {
    id: 3,
    givenName: 'Casey',
    surname: 'Fields',
    initials: 'CF'
}, {
    id: 4,
    givenName: 'Sam',
    surname: 'Johns',
    initials: 'SJ'
}, {
    id: 5,
    givenName: 'Thomas',
    surname: 'Smith',
    initials: 'TS'
}, {
    id: 6,
    givenName: 'Jack',
    surname: 'Jenson',
    initials: 'JJ'
}];
```

```
export const projects = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Project 1',
    ownersId: [
        1,
        2,
        5,
        6,
    ]}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Project 2',
    ownersId: [
        1,
        3,
    ]}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Project 3',
    ownersId: [
        1,
        2,
        4,
        3, 
    ]}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Project 4',
    ownersId: [
        1,  
    ]}, {
}]
```

What I am trying to do is loop over the details of `project` which I have successfully done using `v-for`. What I am stuck on is displaying a loop within the loop that displays all the `users` names using the IDs in  the `ownersId` field.

```
<template>
    <div class="demo">
        <div 
            v-for="project in projects"  
            v-bind:key="project.id" 
        >
            <h4><strong>{{ project.name }}</strong></h4>
            <div v-if="project.ownersId" >
                Shared with {{ project.ownersId.length }} others
            </div>
            <div>
                <!-- Loop of the list of names from IDs goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { projects } from '../data/example';
import { users }  from '../data/example';

export default {
    name: "Demo",
    data() {
        return {
            projects,
            users,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your user data array to a computed object for fast lookup.  Then there will only be 1 data iteration, to create the object.  The object will also be cached because it's a computed so re-renders won't trigger the iteration again.

This could prevent a lot of excess array looping and finding, which might be important for performance with larger datasets, especially if the template is re-rendered for any reason.

```
computed: {
  userData() {
    const userData = {};
    this.users.forEach(user => {
      userData[user.id] = user;
    });
    return userData;
  }
}
```

*Template*

```html
<div 
    v-for="project in projects"  
    v-bind:key="project.id" 
>
    <h4><strong>{{ project.name }}</strong></h4>
    <div v-if="project.ownersId" >
        Shared with {{ project.ownersId.length }} others
    </div>
    <div>
        <div v-for="userId in project.ownersId" :key="userId">
            {{ userData[userId] }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/40xvdwhq/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First time using ```computed:``` and didn't know where it should go in the syntax, did figure out in the end. Probably a stupid question but for performance where should the computed object sit in a larger project, in the component.vue or main.js level?

Comment: You're welcome.  To answer your followup:  I would keep the computed with the component, or this is the kind of state you might keep in Vuex.  Either way it won't affect performance much if at all.  While it's true that navigating away from the component and back will cause the 1 iteration to happen again, it's only 1 iteration per visit, even if there were 100 users and 100 projects.  On the other hand, using array finds for 100 projects with 4 users each would be 400 iterations per visit, per render.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SC.

Given that these are 2 arrays, I feel the best way is to simply make a method that returns the user data based on the project, then loop through that data.

```js
methods:{
 getUserList(project){
  return project.ownersId.map(id=>
    users.find(user=>user.id===id)
   )
 }
}
```

then use this method like so

```html
<div v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
...
  <!-- Loop of the list of names from IDs goes here -->
  <template v-for="user in getUserList(project)" :key="user.id"> 
    {{ user }}
  </template>
...
</div>
```